# Cannot Duplicate Quiz in moodle

Tags: php, sql, moodle

HELP,

I tried to duplicate the quiz in moodle 3.9 but it freezes, All the debug options are on but still, there's no issue in front.

FYI: I can still duplicate the attendance and PDFs in a course but not a quiz

[image: Debug Settings]
[image: Stuck At loading]

Comment: Try with the debug level set to developer

Comment: Hey, @RussellEngland No not even switching it to developer showed me any error. I have checked the error log but like there nothing going there too, Error logs have things dated back in 2021

Answer (score 0):

Not the answer but some troubleshooting

1. Turn on debugging to developer level (which you have already tried)
2. Clear the cache - this usually fixes 90% of problems

https://docs.moodle.org/400/en/Developer_tools#Purge_all_caches

3. Display the javacript console in case its a javascript bug

https://developer.chrome.com/docs/devtools/open/

4. Try a different browser + make sure you are logged in as admin
5. Use course backup and restore via moodle and/or command line to see if there are any errors

https://docs.moodle.org/311/en/Course_backup#Backup_via_CLI_for_administrators

6. Check/increase the value for PHP execution time in case its timing out

https://docs.moodle.org/22/en/Administration_FAQ#How_to_change_the_maximum_execution_time

7. Check if the code has been modified - download/git checkout the exact version of Moodle in a separate directory - then I personally use Meld to compare the directories

https://meldmerge.org/

8. Backup the code and database onto a dev site

8a. Manually add debugging to the `config.php` file in the dev site

```
$CFG->debug = E_ALL | E_STRICT;
$CFG->debugdisplay = 1;
```

8b. Test copy quiz on the dev site there in case its an environment issue

8c. Upgrade the dev site to the latest version of 3.9.x in case its a Moodle bug - if that works then check the git log for the commit that fixed the bug